# Read excel data using dataprovider and java 8

Tags: foreach, java-8, java-stream, testng-dataprovider

I already have a dataprovider method to read data - i.e it will loop through the excel using two for loops and put that into an object array.
Now I want to simplify it instead of using for loops.

I have tried the following, but dont know how to put that into an object array.

**New code:**

```
        data = new String[rowCount][columnCount];
        DataFormatter format = new DataFormatter();

        // loop through the rows

        sheet.forEach(row -> {
            row.forEach(cell -> {
            String  cellValue = format.formatCellValue(cell);
            });
```

**old code:**

```
        // loop through the rows
                    for(int i=1; i <rowCount+1; i++){
                        try {
                            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                            for(int j=0; j <columnCount; j++){ // loop through the columns
                                try {
                                    String cellValue = ""; 
                                    try{ 
                                        Cell cel = row.getCell(j); 
                                        cellValue =  format.formatCellValue(cel);

                                        }

                                    catch(NullPointerException e){

                        }
                        data[i-1][j]  = cellValue; // add to the data array
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }               
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is data structure of `sheet` .

Comment: `data = IntStream.range(0, rowCount) .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, columnCount) .mapToObj(j -> format.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j))) .toArray(String[]::new)) .toArray(String[][]::new);`